# Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Exercise[]>'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs6

### I use

Angular CLI: 6.0.8

Node: 8.11.3

I just learned Udemy - Angular (Full App) with Angular Material, Angularfire & NgRx.
Up on lesson 72 Listening to Value Changes (of_Firestore) I have an error

```js
export class NewTrainingComponent implements OnInit {
  exercises: Observable<Exercise[]>;

  constructor(
    private trainingService: TrainingService,
    private db: AngularFirestore) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.exercises = this.db
      .collection('availableExercises')
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
          map(docArray => {
          return docArray.map(doc => {
            return {
              id: doc.payload.doc.id,
              name: doc.payload.doc.data().name,
              duration: doc.payload.doc.data().duration,
              calories: doc.payload.doc.data().calories
            };
          });
        })
      ).subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result);
      });
  }

  onStartTraining(form: NgForm) {
    this.trainingService.startExercise(form.value.exercise);
  }

}
```

> error TS2322: Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
>
> error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}'.
>
> error TS2339: Property 'duration' does not exist on type '{}'.
>
> error TS2339: Property 'calories' does not exist on type '{}'.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is very obvious. The `exercises` is a type of `Observable` as you have defined:

```
exercises: Observable<Exercise[]>;
```

But you assign it to a subscription in your `ngOnInit()` method.

Your `ngOnInit()` method should be like the following (do not make the assignment to `exercises`):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.db
      .collection('availableExercises')
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
          map(docArray => {
          return docArray.map(doc => {
            return {
              id: doc.payload.doc.id,
              name: doc.payload.doc.data().name,
              duration: doc.payload.doc.data().duration,
              calories: doc.payload.doc.data().calories
            };
          });
        })
      ).subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Working but still a little error 

error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}'.
error TS2339: Property 'duration' does not exist on type '{}'.
error TS2339: Property 'calories' does not exist on type '{}'.

Comment: You may try these: name: doc.payload.doc.data()['name'] and duration: doc.payload.doc.data()['duration']

Comment: Happy the issue is solved. Good luck in your project. :)